# show/hide with same ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I searched a lot on Stackoverflow, solution for my question, but no one of them helped me. I have a multiple show/hide (toggle) content, with same id's and I want to make, that the only one of them, what I need, opens, not all of them. There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p6a7k3cw/2/) You can test it.

This is my JavaScript

```
$("#view").click(function(){
  $('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: `id` should be unique in a page.

Comment: You're better off using unique IDs and use classes for styling etc. across multiple elements.

Comment: You can use jquery UIs accordion for this https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @Matthijs is that really matters now?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144988/jquery-accordion-functionality-panel-opens-when-it-shouldnt-be-opening/40179094#40179094

Comment: Change `$('.hidden-content')` to `$(this).parent().next('.hidden-content')`

Comment: Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6a7k3cw/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate `id` attributes within a single document. When you do only the first element with the given `id` is recognised; hence the issue you've seen.

Instead change the `view` elements to use a class, then use the `this` reference within the `click` event handler to traverse the DOM to find the related `.hidden-content` element and toggle it. Try this:

```js
$(".view").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.div').find('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 400px;
}
.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
.view {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}
.hidden-content .active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad practice to use same id for more than one elements.

You can try the following

```
<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>
<div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
</div>
```

and your jquery will look like the following

```
$(".view").click(function(){
  $(this).parent('.content').next('.hiddencontent').slideToggle(500).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your click event as follows to make it work.

```
$("div[id='view']").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(500).toggleClass("active");
});
```

**Note**: You shouldn't have the same id for multiple elements, id attribute value should be unique why because the id attribute is used to identify an element uniquely in the DOM. You can have the same class name for different elements.

Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498617/4808901) it provides more information on how things work when multiple elements have the same id attribute value.

```js
$("div[id='view']").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(500).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 400px;
}
.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
#view {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}
.hidden-content .active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the `id` to `class`. And for accordion, you can use like below.

HTML,

```
<div class="div">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="view">view/edit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-content">
        hidden content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="view">view/edit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-content">
        hidden content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="view">view/edit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-content">
        hidden content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="view">view/edit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-content">
        hidden content
    </div>
</div>
```

Js,

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hidden-content").hide();
    $(".view").on('click', function(){

        $(this).parents().parents().find(".hidden-content").slideToggle(500).toggleClass("active");

        if($(this).parents().parents().siblings().find(".hidden-content").hasClass('active')){
            $(this).parents().parents().siblings().find(".hidden-content").removeClass('active');
            $(this).parents().parents().siblings().find(".hidden-content").hide();
        }
    });
});

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".view").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.div').find('.hidden-content').slideToggle(200).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 400px;
}
.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
.view {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}
.hidden-content .active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="view">view/edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-content">
    hidden content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: someone say bad practice to same id but what if i loop every tr ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.